# MySQLConnector installation fails every time

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

I've been trying to install MySQL Connector 6.9.4 (NET) for Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate but for some reason the MySQL Connection database does not appear inside Visual Studio.

Here's a screenshot of Programs and Features in Windows:
 [image: Windows Programs and Features]

... and heres one of the Data Sources in Visual Studio 2012, running a C# Windows Forms Project:
[image: Data Sources Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the connector and install version 6.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 6.7, the Visual Studio integration comes in a separate package.  You should download the full Windows Installer available at http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html and install it.

If you install only the above driver, then you can access MySQL directly from your code but nothing else.

Comment: Apparently installation order is important, requiring the VS Integration app to be installed before the connector. Not doing so seems to result in the missing data source problem in the OP.